# Stopping JavaScript code execution immediately after a redirect in Chrome DevTools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, redirect, google-chrome-devtools

I've got a scenario where a user receives a round-trip redirect via query string from one site to another.

For instance, the user starts on `example-site-a.com`, gets redirected to `example-site-b.com?redirectBackTo=example-site-a.com`, and is redirected back to the original site by setting the `window.location.href` to the query string value.

I would like to debug/step through JavaScript located on the second site, but the second redirect happens in the blink of an eye.

Say my JavaScript on `example-site-b.com` looks like this:

```
<script>
    alert("debug!");
    debugger;
    console.log("test");
</script>
```

`alert()` doesn't pause the code execution and `debugger` isn't working either.  I also tried setting an Event Listener Breakpoint in Chrome DevTools to pause on `Script First Statement`, but the `console.log` statement is still eluding me.

I'm just looking to step through the above code on `example-site-b`.  Any ideas?

Comment: What is causing this redirect? WIll it wait for all JS to have stopped running? In that case you can use a setTimeout so you have time to press the F12 button. If the redirect will happen serverside or will not wait for JS in site-b to finish, you'll have to remove the redirect mechanism for a bit and just do a manual redirect to site-b to test.

Comment: @Shilly I'm using `window.location.href` to redirect to site B - site B sets a cookie in JavaScript and immediately redirects back to site A using `window.location.href`.

Comment: A `Script First Statement` event breakpoint should do the trick. Can you describe what you're seeing?

Comment: @KayceBasques Just seeing site B redirect to site A in the blink of an eye.  I can step through all JavaScript located in `.js` files when `Script First Statement` is checked off, but not the on-page `<script>` code I need to step through.

Comment: @Shilly This insanely hacky / beautiful approach ended up working for me like a charm.  Thank you!  Can you write up your response as an answer so I can mark it as "accepted"?

Comment: Possibly easier-- Chrome Dev Tools => Sources Tab => In the right hand pane, expand "Event Listener Breakpoints" => Expand the "Load" checkbox tree => Check any state change for which you'd like a breakpoint to trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alex said that this suggestion from Shilly did the trick:

> What is causing this redirect? WIll it wait for all JS to have stopped running? In that case you can use a setTimeout so you have time to press the F12 button. If the redirect will happen serverside or will not wait for JS in site-b to finish, you'll have to remove the redirect mechanism for a bit and just do a manual redirect to site-b to test.